# Mobile Safari - JavaScript click event breaks copy and paste

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, mobile-safari

When you bind a click event to any element in Mobile Safari copy and paste is prevented, does anyone know a workaround for this!?

```
<span onclick="void(0);">This text cannot be cut or copied and a -webkit-tap-highlight-color style is automatically applied.</span>
```

This seems like such a massive bug to me, especially if you're delegating events from a parent element such as the body...

For a demonstration of the issue try copying text using mobile safari (iPhone or iPad) within this demo: http://jsbin.com/ikileb/1/

NOTE: it appears to be fine if you delegate the event from the body but if it's delegated from any other element in the DOM the `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` is applied and copy and paste is prevented within the entire element.

Comment: It's not really a bug I think, but check out this previous question where they had success with the addEventListener('touchstart');

Comment: @Marcus - Unfortunately touchstart isn't a valid alternative to click as they behave differently - the biggest concern being touchstart doesn't distinguish between a click and a scroll gesture so I still believe this to be a bug.

Comment: If you need to, you can use touchstart+touchmove+touchend, and set a swiping=true flag on touchmove to only run your event on click. As a side note, Apple documentation officially lists copy/cut events as unsupported, so you're right - this may be a bug with no easy fix. See  http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW1

Comment: How about bind event using non-inline JS way? Like JQuery way `$('span').click(function(){alert('Hey!');});`?

Answer (score 0):

No,the only way is change your UX behave,like add a click-able button.you can check out G+ for mobile.

Comment: I'm not sure how this relates to UX?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, this solution requires some jQuery.

The example I provide is a more complex example using a traditional keyboard/mouse.  But for touch devices, just follow the left-click portions.

1. left-click will bring up a link in the same window
2. right-click will bring up a link in a new window
3. left-click drag to select allows for copy and paste still (in my scenario, the desktop user would use their copy/paste keystroke, not the right-click)

Not 100% sure about the specifics for Safari, but this should generally work for all modern browsers.

Here is a table of links I want to access:

```
<table>
<tr class="row"><td>http://google.com</td></tr>
<tr class="row"><td>http://teslamotors.com</td></tr>
<tr class="row"><td>http://solarcity.com</td></tr>
</table>
```

Here's the script using a current version of jQuery to handle `mousedown` and `mouseup` binding:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var lastMouseDownEvent = null;

    // capture your last "mousedown" event and store it
    $(".row").mousedown(function(event) {
        console.log(event); // lets see the data in your Developer Mode log
        lastMouseDownEvent = event;
    });

    // catch the "mouseup" event and compare the distance from "mousedown"
    $(".row").mousedown(function(event) {
        console.log(event);

        var href = $(this).find("td").html();
        switch(event.which) {
            case 1: // left click
                // only process left click if mousedown and mouseup occur at the same location on screen.
                // NOTE: for my mom's shaky hand I added the 5 pixel allowance.
                if (Math.abs(event.clientX-lastMouseDownEvent.clientX) < 5 &&
                    Math.abs(event.clientY-lastMouseDownEvent.clientY < 5))
                    window.location.href = href;
                break;
            case 2: // right click
                window.open(href);
                break;
        }
        lastMouseDownEvent = null;
    });


});
</script>
```